# Can Rails and PHP access the same SQL database at different times? How?

Tags: php, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a webpage where PHP will routinely write to a SQL database.

Is there a way to also create a Ruby on Rails application which accesses/reads from the same database by clicking a different link on the HTML page?

Answer (score 2):

Each popular database out there is designed to handle many requests at the same time, it's the main feature and idea of databases, otherwise it would have terrible performance, speed and security: imagine someone writing/reading there, so everyone else should wait?
Language is just a tool to connect and operate database: language still uses SQL syntax so every language ends up executing SQL statements in DB. So to answer your question: language doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. But keep in mind that Rails has a convention of enforcing constraints and integrity at the application level. This means that if you have a table called users and you've set up your User model to validate that a user must have an email address, then this constraint only applies to your Rails application.

Because of that, you have to make sure your PHP application doesn't manipulate the database in ways that cause your Rails application to malfunction. E.g. inserting a user without an e-mail address.

Comment: Or better, put the data integrity logic inside the database where it belongs and tell Rails to grow up and stop having such a foolish attitude towards databases. But kudos for mentioning the "Rails doesn't play well with others" problem.

Comment: @muistooshort This a matter of preference. As long as the databases cannot offer the same validation framework as Rails, I am happy to have Rails safeguarding my database with explicit validation declaration in my code rather than (vendor-specific) constraints inside the production database.

I only know MySQL and SQLite and I wouldn't know how to instruct them to perform a regex on a column or ensure that only validated users can set their comments published attribute to true.

Perhaps you know ways?

Comment: Switch to a database that has proper support for [CHECK constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2410), then you can easily constrain your columns however you need. Toss in a reasonably functional procedural language and you can put critical constraints inside the database and not have to worry about all the race conditions and multi-client problems. IMO you should treat your database as a separate application whose job is to manage your data; ensuring data consistency is the database's job. The Rails attitude is immature and full of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the proper API according to the technology stack you're using.

I'd recommend using separate usernames on the DB side for each solution in order to differentiate when reading server DB logs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible.  For the most part, databases are independent of applications.  Any application that can connect to a database and send valid sql can connect to it.

For example, let's say you have a php website that interacts with a sql server database.  If you have Management Studio, which is another application, installed on your computer, and you have permission, you can connect to that database and run queries.

For the same database, if I had the connection credentials, I could write a ColdFusion or .net web page that queries it.  The database doesn't care about the application that is calling it.  It only cares about permissions and valid sql.

Answer (score -2):

You can have a model in your rails app for, for example `transactions`:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :price, :product
end
```

Then in your `config/database.yml`, you can write the config for the database to be:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: development
  host: 11.111.11.11 # any host name
  port: 3306
  username: username
  password: password

test:
  ...
```

Remember to put `mysql2` gem in your `Gemfile`

From the PHP side, you can connect to this database as usual:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('11.111.11.11', 'username', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// select correct db for environment
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('development', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions";
$results = mysql_query($sql);
// ...
?>
```

Comment: This isn't really what the question is about. He doesn't want multiple databases. He wants multiple applications sharing one database.

Comment: This offers that functionality entirely.